# CSV Reader object getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm creating a `csv.reader` object, setting it as an instance variable, but then when I try to iterate through it I get an error saying I'm trying to operate on a closed file.  Is the `reader` still linked to the file somehow?  I'm assigning it within my `with open(blah)` block, so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
    def __init__(self, infile, header_file, transact_file):
        self.infile = infile
        self.header_of = header_file
        self.transact_of = transact_file

    def create_reader(self):
        """Create a csv reader."""

        with open(self.infile, 'r') as inf:
            logging.info('Infile name: {0}'.format(inf))
            self.csv_reader = reader(inf, quotechar='"')

    def parse_headers(self):
        """Separate header files ("H", "S") from transaction files."""

        headers = []
        transactions = []

        for row in self.csv_reader:
            row_type = row[0]
            logging.info('Row type is: {0}'.format(row_type))
            if row_type == 'H':
                logging.info('Row added to header list.')
                headers.append(row)
            elif row_type == 'S':
                if row not in headers:
                    logging.info('Row added to header list.')
                    headers.append(row)
            else:
                logging.info('Row added to transaction list.')
                transactions.append(row)

        # Debugging and verification
        logging.info('Header list contains: {0}'.format('\n'.join([str(header) for header
            in headers])))
        logging.info('Transaction list contains: {0}'.format(
            '\n'.join([str(trans) for trans in transactions])))
```

Here is my error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                    x
  File "./gen_pre.py", line 155, in <module>                                                                          x
    main()                                                                                                            x
  File "./gen_pre.py", line 25, in main                                                                               x
    parser.run_process()                                                                                              x
  File "./gen_pre.py", line 140, in run_process                                                                       x
    self.parse_headers()                                                                                              x
  File "./gen_pre.py", line 68, in parse_headers                                                                      x
    for row in self.csv_reader:                                                                                       x
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: this line may be consuming the file to the end "logging.info('Infile name: {0}'.format(inf)) " I think you meant to do "logging.info('Infile name: {0}'.format(self.infile))" or  "logging.info('Infile name: {0}'.format(inf.name))"

Comment: @Rob I don't think just calling the variable name like that would do anything to it. You are correct in that the OP probably wants the file*name* not the file*handle* /file*descriptor*, but that shouldn't be what's causing the OP's issue.

Comment: @dwanderson, Yeah I think you are right.. it should just dump a string representation of the file descriptor. furas is right.. when he returns from the create_reader method it exists the with block which closes the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with` automatically closes the file when you leave the block.

You have to do

```
self.inf = open(self.infile, 'r')

self.csv_reader = reader(self.inf, quotechar='"') # self.inf
```

and you will have to close the file manually.

```
def close_reader(self):
    self.csv_reader.close()
    self.inf.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain why the reader object depends on the file being open?  Does it not all read in at once?  Is it a generator or something?

Comment: `with` closes file before you leave `create_reader` so file is closed before you even start to read from this file. Reader reads from file when you run `for row in self.csv_reader`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Context managers are great because they automatically close files for you.  Instead of manually opening and closing the file, you could read the whole file and pass a list of the rows to the CSV reader:

```
def create_reader(self):
    """Create a csv reader."""
    with open(self.infile, 'r') as inf:
        logging.info('Infile name: {0}'.format(inf))
        file_data = inf.readlines()
    self.csv_reader = reader(file_data, quotechar='"')
```

The `csv.reader` object will accept anything it can iterate over, so a list of each line in the file (from `readlines`) will work fine.